# Where is NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.SimplePointInRing()?

Tags: c#, nettopologysuite

We're moving a project from .NET 4.5.2 to .NET 5.0. In the process, this means moving a dependency on the NetTopologySuite NuGet package from v1.14.0 to v2.2.0.

In v1.14.0, there are a number of places where we're using the NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.SimplePointInRing class.

In v2.2.0, there is no SimplePointInRing class in the NetTopologySuite.Algorithm. Or at least, not in any of the NuGet Packages we've installed:

- NetToplogySuite v2.2.0
- NetToplogySuite.Core v1.15.3
- NetToplogySuite.IO.GeoJson v2.0.4

Has it been deprecated? Removed? Moved to a new NuGet package?

Comment: Please don't mix NTS v1.15.3 and v2.2. What do you need NTS v1.15.3 for?
Have a look at https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0-from-1.x

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it was removed in v1.15.0 because v1.15.0-pre2 still had a SimplePointInRing class in that namespace.

Since things have changed a bit, the closest "replacement" I have found so far is the [LocatePointInRing(Coordinate p, CoordinateSequence ring) method inside the NetTopologySuite.Tests.NUnit.Algorithm namespace.](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/blob/develop/test/NetTopologySuite.Tests.NUnit/Algorithm/NonRobustRayCrossingCounter.cs)

Comment: I was going to suggest PointLocation.IsInRing - which may allow you to facade away this easier.  Either would seem to work.